# PHP Get local machine time (windows or linux)

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

I'm writing a php bot which people will be running, this bot requires accurate time in order to function correctly. I'm currently using a timestamp function as follows:

```
//return string of a timestamp
private function timestamp()
{
    $date = date_create();
    return "(" . $date->format('H:i:s') . ")";
}
```

Now, I understand that there is a function to set the timezone

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-timezone-set.php

My issue is that I will have users, users who know very little if not anything about PHP to set the timezones. I can't rely on them to set their own timezones as it will create headaches with formatting and typos, at the very least, if we could set the timezones via numbers instead of locations, for example my timezone is -6...

```
date_default_timezone_set("-6");
```

I have found functions of people who have tried to create a function in order to set the local machine's time, but their functions are either outdated or not working.

Is there a function or an alternative robust way to get the local time for either a linux and windows machine for php 5.0+.

Thanks again for your help.

EDIT: even localtime() returns a wrong time...

Comment: When your users run this PHP script on their machine, the timezone will already be set by the system. So there seems to be no need to set it yourself.

Comment: Well seeing how my machine is set to 16:08 and it returns 23:08 I think I do... no idea why PHP can't just pull the local machine's time zone itself.

Comment: @olaf apparently pre php 5.3,the time zone is not set by default in php ini

Comment: I'm using XAMPP which uses PHP 5.4.7 according to http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

Comment: Problem with setting timezones like "-6" is that they break when DST starts or ends... For example, I'm in CET now (December), and CEST in summer. The only reliable way to deal with this is to use "complete" timezones, like "Europe/Rome".

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the [supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) or set one with [other timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) like

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT' . '-6');
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. This is much simpler then what I was doing by creating a huge array of timezones that a user would of had to pick from. The only bad part about this is that it still requires user input, o well though. Until I figure out an easier way, it's getting done this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can current local time via below Javascript.

```
    <script>

        // For 24 hours    

        var ct = new Date();
        var hr = ct.getHours();
        var mt = ct.getMinutes();
        if (mt < 10) {
            mt = "0" + mt;
        }
        document.write("<b>" + hr + ":" + mt + " " + "</b>");    


        // For 12 hours (AM / PM)

        var ct = new Date();
        var hr = ct.getHours();
        var mt = ct.getMinutes();

        var ampm = "AM";

        if (hr >= 12) {
            ampm = "PM";
            hr = hr - 12;
        }
        if (hr == 0) {
            hr = 12;
        }
        if (mt < 10) {
            mt = "0" + mt;
        }

        document.write("<b>" + hr + ":" + mt + " " + ampm + "</b>");

   </script>
```